# Reading multiple inputs

Tags: shell

Is there a way to read multiple inputs that are passed through Command Line from user?
I want to access each one of them  and process an operation upon each.
For ex:

Enter Your Inputs:

```
11111
22222
33333
44444
55555
66666
77777
```

Now, I want to access each of the inputs from "11111" to "77777". If any of you knows any method, pls share.

Comment: You will need to call `read` in a loop.

Comment: I tried but I could not get any idea to access them through loop. ANy idea on this/concept???

Comment: You need show your approach in your question. If not code at least provide some pseudo code.